# How to embed and render openTK GLControl in Windows Form's User control?

Tags: winforms, opengl, opentk

I am new to Windows Forms and OpenTK . I have to render and embed the OpenTK GLControl into windows forms user control . How to do that?
   And is there any tutorials available for that?

Comment: See [OpenTK windows forms example](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl/tree/master/OpenTK_windows_forms/OpenTK_windows_forms_example_1)